# Execute listener corresponding to selected tab in p:tabview on tabChange event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to fetch corresponding data into bean whenever some certain `tab` is selected from the `tabview`. For this I have been trying to use `f:event` with `preRenderComponent` but that doesnt help with desired.

How can I execute listener corresponding to the tab whenever a certain tab is selected in tabview.

```
               <p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="false">
                    <p:tab title="People I'm following" >
                        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{listRetriever.retrieveFollowies()}"/>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{listRetriever.list}" var="person">
                            #{person}<br/>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="People following me" >
                        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{listRetriever.retrieveFollowers()}"/>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{listRetriever.list}" var="person">
                            #{person}<br/>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TabChangeEvent passes you the selected tab instance, live sample;

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabviewChangeListener.jsf